# Define common mock objects for many test classes

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I'm learning unit testing with Spring Boot. I've created a stub object from Spring Data repository class using Mockito. All works fine, here's a code:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceTest {

@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@BeforeAll
public void  configureMock() {
    User user = new User("mishenev",
            "Dmitrii",
            "Mishenev",
            "123",
            "mishenev.8@gmailcom",
            new UserSettings());
    when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
    when(userRepository.findUserByUserName(anyString())).thenReturn(user);

 // .. Tests
}
```

But it's kind of boilerplate style to use this @BeforeAll test repository configuration for each class, if we don't need different stub behaviour. Then i tried to use ***@TestConfiguration***

```
@TestConfiguration
 public class SpringRepositoryTestConfiguration {

@Bean
public UserRepository userRepository () {
    UserRepository userRepository = Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);
    // Configuring mock's behaviour
    return userRepository;
    }
}
```

After that i used

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringRepositoryTestConfiguration.class)
```

But i can't using `@MockBean` to autowire repository in `UserService` now.
I want to understand is it possible to take out and use all test `Repository` type stubs in one configuration class. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this

```
class TestConfig {

   @Bean
   UserRepository userRepository() {
       final UserRepository repo = mock(UserRepository.class);
       .. do mocking ..
       return repo;

   }

}
```

Then you can just `@Import(TestConfig.class)` where you need it